# Solving differential eqation x''(t)+a x'(t) x(t)+b x(t)^3-c x(t)^2=0 symbolically

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I can't solve the following differential equation:

```
DSolve[{x''[t] + a x[t] x'[t] + b x[t]^3 - c x[t]^2 == 0}, {x[t]}, t]
```

It returns the original input.

How can we get a general symbolic solution?

Comment: Welcome to Mma.S.E. Firstly, it is expected to provide the code you tried. Secondly, do you have any reasons to believe that this D.E has an analytic solution?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please add copy-paste-able code (not images) so that forum participants can copy and paste it to their notebook environments to replicate the errors or difficulties you face. The comments and answers will consequently be more focused. Copy directly from your 
input cell, click the `Edit` button under your post and format as code using the `{  }` icon in the Edit window. Thanks

Comment: Many ODEs do not have symbolic solutions.  Do you have reason to believe that this one does?

Answer (score 8):

This has no analytical solution. To see this more clearly, you can convert this to first order ode.

This is a nonlinear second order ode with missing independent variable $t$. In such cases the ode can be converted to first order using the substitution $x'(t)=p(x)$. i.e. by making the dependent variable $x$ an independent variable, and introducing a new dependent variable $p(x)$. This is done using this code

```
ClearAll[x, t, a, b, c]
ode = x''[t] + a x[t] x'[t] + b x[t]^3 - c x[t]^2 == 0
ode = ode /. D[x[t], {t, 2}] -> p[x]*p'[x]
ode = ode /. D[x[t], t] -> p[x]
ode = ode /. x[t] -> x
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the new first order ode is

```
odeFirstOrder = -c x^2 + b x^3 + a x p[x] + p[x] p'[x]==0
```

If we can solve this, then we can solve the original second order ode for $x(t)$ by integration (assuming the integration can be solved) since $x'(t)=p(x)$

The problem is that the above is an [Abel ode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind). Specifically, in Maple classification, this is called [Abel second type, class A](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor%2FAbel2A). (note that there is an Abel first type and Abel second type ode's).

> There is as yet no general solution for this ODE.

I tried to do the transformation above using the new function [DSolveChangeVariables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveChangeVariables.html) but I could not. By hand, it is done using chain rule like this:

\begin{gather*}
\boxed{x^{\prime \prime}+a x x^{\prime}+b x^{3}-c x^{2}=0}
\end{gather*}
This is missing independent variable second order ode. Solved by reduction of order by using substitution which makes the dependent variable $x$ an independent variable. Using
\begin{align*}
x' &= p(x)
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
x'' &= \frac{dp}{dt}\\ 
          &= \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dp}{dx}\\ 
          &= p \frac{dp}{dx}
\end{align*}
Hence the ode becomes
\begin{align*}
p \left(x \right) \left(\frac{d}{d x}p \left(x \right)\right)+a x p \left(x \right)+b \,x^{3}-c \,x^{2} = 0
\end{align*}
Which is now solved as first order ode for $p(x)$. But neither Maple, nor Mathematica can solve this first order ode.